# How do I prove two non parallel planes' locus of intersection will always be a line

Tags: geometry

If I have two 3D equations of the form ax+by+cz=d , how do I prove the locus of their intersection is a 3D straight line?

Comment: 3D or 2D, those are linear equations, and so they describe planes in 3D, and lines in 2D.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: How do you define “line?”

Answer (score 0):

use $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ and $$a'x+b'y+c'z+d'=0$$ ans solve the System
the solution of this System is given by $$ \left\{ x={\frac {Bcz-Cbz+Bd- \left( D \right) b}{Ab-Ba}},y=-{\frac {
Acz-Caz+Ad- \left( D \right) a}{Ab-Ba}},z=z \right\} 
$$
for clarification i have used $$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$ for the second equation

Comment: could you elaborate, I know the cartesian form of a line , but I don't know how to come to it from the above 2 equations.

Comment: thank a lot :):)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very general proof of that using vectors. In the equation of a plane
$$ ax + by + cz + d = 0 $$ 
the constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the components of the vector that is normal to that plane (it defines its orientation in space). Suppose your two planes have normal vectors $\mathbf n_1$ and $\mathbf n_2$ (which are not parallel since your planes are not parallel). Then if A and B are any two points in their intersection, $\rm\overrightarrow{AB}$ must be perpendicular to both $\bf n_1$ and $\bf n_2$ and thus parallel to their cross product. This proves that any three points A, B, and C in the intersection are collinear, since $\rm\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\rm\overrightarrow{AC}$ are both parallel to $\bf n_1 \times n_2$. (In fact, this cross product is the direction vector of the intersection line.)